# Multibib clean up my author information

Tags: multibib, affiliation

I am writing an article with multiple references. I need my author email and current affiliation to appear in the footnote. However, as soon as I imported multibib package the footnote disappeared. Is there a way to enforce the footnote to go alone with the reference?

Attached is my code

```
\documentclass[aps,prb,twocolumn,showpacs,superscriptaddress,amsmath,amssymb]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multibib}  
\usepackage[pdftex,bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen,bookmarksnumbered,
                colorlinks,
                linkcolor=blue,
                citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage{multirow}

%%%%%%%%% some formatting stuff


\begin{document}
\title{The title}


\author{Author1}
\email[helpme@gmail.com]{}
\affiliation{Here}

\author{Author2}
\altaffiliation[Now at ]{Somewhere else}
\affiliation{Here}

\author{Boss}
\email[my email]{}
\affiliation{Here}


\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by an update to the document class as noted in the comments.